# Is there a way to update every window when a new theme has been selected in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code right here:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.change_look_and_feel('GreenTan')
color_list = sg.list_of_look_and_feel_values()
color_list.sort()
layout = [[sg.Text('Theme Browser')],
          [sg.Text('Click on a theme.')],
          [sg.Listbox(values=color_list,
                      size=(20, 12), key='-LIST-', enable_events=True)],
          [sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Look and Feel Browser', layout)

while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break

    themeNow = values['-LIST-'][0]
    sg.theme(themeNow)
    sg.change_look_and_feel(themeNow)
    window.refresh()
    sg.popup("Changed theme to " + themeNow)

window.close()
```

But the window is not updating it's theme when a user clicks on a new theme. Only the popup has it's theme updated (since it's a new window).

I do not know how to refresh all the windows (even though I have 1 window, I know...)

Comment: Until now, there's no way to update theme. The only way you have to rebuild all windows.  Call a function with 'new' layout and return `sg,Window`.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: New theme won't be applied if a window already finalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example that allows you to select a new theme from a theme browser showing all themes -no combo selection is needed- and updates a window by closing and recreating it.

Here is the source code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

selected_theme = 'LightGreen'
sg.theme(selected_theme)

theme_list = sg.theme_list()
theme_list.sort()

NUM_COLUMNS = 8
theme_list_size = len(theme_list)
num_rows = int(theme_list_size/NUM_COLUMNS)


def create_theme_box(theme_index):  
    sg.theme(theme_list[theme_index])
    return sg.Column(
        [
            [sg.Text('' + theme_list[theme_index], size=(16,1))] +
            [sg.Button('Select', k=str(theme_index)),] ,
        ]
    )


def create_theme_example(theme):
    sg.theme(theme)
    theme_frame = [
        [sg.Checkbox('Checkbox')] +
                [sg.Slider(range=(0, 100), orientation='horizontal', size=(20, None), default_value=50)] +
                [sg.Button('Button')] +
                [sg.Text('     InputText:'), sg.InputText()],
    ]
    
    theme_example_layout = [
            [sg.Frame(selected_theme, theme_frame)],
        ]

    return sg.Window('Theme Example', theme_example_layout, resizable=True, finalize=True, location=(100,50))


theme_browser_layout = [
    [
        [create_theme_box(column+NUM_COLUMNS*row) for column in range(0, NUM_COLUMNS)] for row in range(0, num_rows)
    ],
    [
        create_theme_box(column + int(theme_list_size/NUM_COLUMNS)*NUM_COLUMNS) for column in range(0, (theme_list_size%NUM_COLUMNS))
    ],
]

def main():
    global selected_theme
   
    window_theme_browser = sg.Window('Theme Browser', theme_browser_layout, resizable=True, finalize=True, location=(100,200))
    window = create_theme_example(selected_theme)
    
    while True:
        event, values = window_theme_browser.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break

        window.close()
        selected_theme = theme_list[int(event)]
        print("Selected:",selected_theme )

        window = create_theme_example(selected_theme)   

    window_theme_browser.close()
    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you don't want to close and create the window but just update it with a new theme, and don't mind if it is portable or not, you can do it using tkinter. An example can be found in this thread: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/2437

Answer (score 1):

A new demo was posted showing how to do this on tie PySimpleGUI GitHub.  Look for Demo_Theme_Change_Your_Windows_Theme.py

Here's the source from it:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

"""
    Demo - Changing your window's theme at runtime
    * Create your window using a "window create function"
    * When your window's theme changes, close the window, call the "window create function"
    
    Copyright 2021 PySimpleGUI
"""

# ------------------- Create the window -------------------
def make_window(theme=None):
    if theme:
        sg.theme(theme)
    # -----  Layout & Window Create  -----
    layout = [[sg.T('This is your layout')],
              [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Change Theme'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

    return sg.Window('Pattern for changing theme', layout)


# ------------------- Main Program and Event Loop -------------------
def main():
    window = make_window()

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event == 'Change Theme':      # Theme button clicked, so get new theme and restart window
            event, values = sg.Window('Choose Theme',
                                      [[sg.Combo(sg.theme_list(), readonly=True, k='-THEME LIST-'), sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()]]
                                      ).read(close=True)
            if event == 'OK':
                # ---- Switch to your new theme! ---- IMPORTANT PART OF THE PROGRA<
                window.close()
                window = make_window(values['-THEME LIST-'])

    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```